# appendTo is not a function

Tags: jquery, html

I ran this javascript code in the browser using jquery, and it gave the error in the title

```
var tr = {};var obj ={}; 
obj['amount']=$('#amount').val();   
tr['amount'] = obj['amount'];
obj['qty']=$('#qty').val();     
tr['qty'] = obj['qty'];

var row = $('<tr></tr>');

$.each(tr, function (type, value) {
  $('<td class="input-' + type + ' text-center"></td>').html(value).appendTo(row);
});
```

Can some one point out what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: i made edits, its an object (`var tr = {};var obj ={}; `)

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with also your HTML?

Comment: Are you sure the title of the question is appropriate ? It was `html()` at some point then you edited it.

Comment: I get no such error http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rqwvkutm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to the problem. It occurred that i was using jquery 1.7.1 so i simple upgraded to 1.11.1, and the problem went away

thanks to all those who made efforts

Answer (score 1):

<del>`tr` should be an array, not an object.

More here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/</del>
My bad, `$.each` works also for objects.

The value of `#amount` should be either a json or a string that you'll convert it later to an array (or object). I think this is the step you're missing - converting the value to something that works with `$.each`.